# how to update Object json in class OOP

Tags: javascript, json, class, oop, object

my JSON file

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "task": "go dancing",
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "task": "Walk",
    "status": false
  }
]
```

i got really stuck on my OOP, i tried to find the Property `Status` in my json and i want to update the property boolean tp be `true` from false

here is my code

```
static completed(input) {
    const data = Model.getdAll(); // get './data.json' local host, 
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i].id == input){
        data[i].status = true
        Model.writeFile(data);
        return data
      }
    }
  }
```

when i console.log( on that static method , it was like this

here is my writefile static method

```
static writeFile(data) {
    return fs.writeFileSync("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) , 'utf8');
  }
```

//when i console.log( on that static method , it was like this

```
Model { id: 4, task: 'going to gym', status: true }
```

when i write file inside that for loop and after the forloop the real data is not changed and that `status` still false

Comment: Can you provide some of the data.json contents?

Comment: just updated , look that @kemicofa

Comment: So, does the writeFileSync update the data.json correctly or is it simply the data being sent back that isn't correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to write to the file? So basically; does `writeFileSync` return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Array#find. Object will be a reference to the object inside of the data array, so changing it will also change what's inside of data.

```js
const Model = {
  getdAll: function(){ return [{"id":1,"task":"go dancing","status":!1},{"id":2,"task":"Walk","status":!1}] },
  writeFile: function(data){ console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) }
}

function completed(input){
    const data = Model.getdAll(); // get './data.json' local host,
    const object = data.find(({id})=>id === input);
    
    if(!object) throw new Error("Object not found");
    object.status = true;
    Model.writeFile(data);
    return data;
}

const res = completed(1);
```

You should also keep in mind that [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) does not return anything, but it does throw an error if it failed.

Consider, wrapping it in a try/catch:

```
static writeFile(data) {
   try {
      fs.writeFileSync("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) , 'utf8');
   }
   catch(e){
      console.warn(e.message);
   }
}
```